# What is the 'AT' astronomical catalogue? And the 'TXS' one? As in AT2019dsg and AT2019fdr?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, radio-astronomy, star-catalogues

I cannot find a site stating what the AT or TXS star/astronomy catalogues are, even though some AT and TXS 'events' have been in the news lately....

Comment: Where have they been in the news? Can you add links to articles or papers?

Answer (score 2):

"AT" are sources named by the [transient name server](https://www.wis-tns.org/content/tns-getting-started):

> A name of the form, e.g. 2016ab, defines the object uniquely. Before it is
> spectroscopically classified it will have a prefix of "AT". If classified as a
> SN of whichever type, the prefix changes to "SN".

"TXS" are sources from the [Texas Survey of radio sources](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/W3Browse/all/texas.html):

> The name is constructed from the hours and minutes of right ascension, the sign of declination, and truncated tenths of degrees of declination: hhmmsddd. Suffixes 'A', 'B', etc., are also used in cases where close sources would otherwise have duplicate names, e.g., 'TXS 0001-234A' and 'TXS 0001-234B'.